# Hibernate 5.4.17Final: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver

Tags: java, hibernate

Added latest version of Hibernate to my existing Maven project.

Getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver`
although that package is installed and in the class path. Have tried already to reinstall/reload dependencies but no still the same.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>classic-core-9.0.0.0-423</groupId>
        <artifactId>classic-core-9.0.0.0-423</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\com\xxx\lib\pentaho\classic-core-9.0.0.0-423.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show your pom.xml

Comment: I added the section of my pom.xml file.

Comment: No the whole pom.xml please

Comment: sorry that file is too long to post. System does not allow me to post it.

Comment: Post only the <dependencies> section

Comment: the <dependencies> section is attached. There are a dozen more dependencies related to pentaho which I haven't posted. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that bytebuddy is in two versions and Hibernate requires another version.

Comment: @Simon thanks for your reply. I figured out after clean,compile, run hibernate is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after clean, compile, run hibernate is working now.